# Nonlinear function minimization C++

Tags: c++, matlab, mathematical-optimization, numerical, minimization

I've been trying to port a code from MATLAB to C++, and stumbled on a very unexpected difficulty. I can't seem to find the C++ equivalant to MATLAB's fminunc.

Simply put, the problems definition is minimizing f(x), for a vector x, a scalar function f(x), and intial guess x_0.

My search endeavors thus far have only cropped up a library called MinPack, which fails to adress the case where f(x) is a scalar and x is vector.

Surely a programming language that's as old as time has some freely available implementation of classic numerical recipes for nonlinear optimization? Or am I being overly optimistic here? Even basic approaches such as gradient descent would be a huge improvement over nothing...

Comment: One might view the still-thriving market for Matlab and its ilk as evidence that you are indeed being over-optimistic in your expectations, as evidence that there is money to be made from writing programs for which no well-regarded open-source free programs are generally available. And, on a lighter note, *C++ is as old as time* is a very funny remark.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark god said: `photon_t letThereBeLight() { return light; }`

Comment: In my defense, I *was* being sarcastic in calling C++ as old as time, but it's just a tad older than me, that must count for something.

Comment: `time_t letThereBeCode = 0` is more of an estimate of C's age, not C++.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I'll say I ended up using Purple, which proved to be quite useful: 
http://www.cimne.com/purple/

Answer (score 1):

Check [NLopt](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt) out.  That's what I use first when porting stuff from MATLAB to C / C++ and it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

**My personal choice would be [IPOPT](https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt)**, a general purpose nonlinear solver. It knows far more than you asked for.

The other options would include:

- [Root finding and minimization (from CERN)](http://root.cern.ch/root/html/MATH_MATHMORE_Index.html) (I haven't tried this one)
- [Harwell Subroutine Library](http://www.hsl.rl.ac.uk/archive/index.html)
- [PORT3](http://open-innovation.alcatel-lucent.com/frs/?group_id=30&release_id=10)

The latter would unfortunately involve [interfacing with FORTRAN](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialMixingFortranAndC.html); it is painful and boring but really not a rocket science.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another good one: GSL, in particular http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/gsl-ref_36.html#SEC498